# Django: Can the order_by() be applied to each individual queryset and then combined?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Can the order_by() be applied to each individual queryset and then combined? So that the order for each condition is still maintained? For example:

```
combined_queryset= User.objects.filter(income__gte=5000).order_by('income') | User.objects.filter(income__lt=5000).order_by('-income')
```

Comment: Your example should work as expected. Did you try it ?

Comment: @karthikr I did try it but the the order is not being maintained. The whole queryset is being ordered in descending order :( would you happen to know why?

Comment: Ok, ,then you could use `itertools.chain()`

Comment: @karthikr, thanks it works, I'll post the solution below. I also tried paging the combined_queryset with itertools.chain() using Django's paginator (10 results per page) and it worked. Is the combined_queryset still lazy?

Comment: Ah.. it is not. However, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is.

Comment: @karthikr thanks karthikr, if you want, you can post the solution below and I'll mark your answer correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools` for this

```
import itertools
itertools.chain.from_iterable(qs1, qs2, ..)
```

`from_iterable` does a lazy load ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable))

> Gets chained inputs from a single iterable argument that is evaluated lazily.